# Why is rake running specs and features twice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, cucumber, rake

For a couple of months now I have the problem that running `rake spec cucumber` (or each one separately) runs the specs and/or features always twice. It's kind of annoying, since it makes me wait longer.

Now if I run `rspec` or `cucumber` then the specs/or features only run a single time.

I'm not sure what details I could provide here, so I'll just link the repo here https://github.com/deiga/new-Roydon/tree/feature/allow-orders-without-registeration

Comment: Okay, I moved all the gems from `:test, :development` into `:test` and now specs only run once. Still no Idea why features run twice.

Comment: Do you have other group for your cukes? bdd?

Comment: @lsaffie Not that I'm aware of. Here are my Gemfiles https://github.com/deiga/new-Roydon/blob/feature/allow-orders-without-registeration/Gemfile https://github.com/deiga/new-Roydon/blob/feature/allow-orders-without-registeration/gemfiles/Gemfile.devel

Comment: Hard to tell but I would start by making sure I there are no reported bugs with my rspec/cucumber gem, also trying to run the command with RAILS_ENV=test

Comment: I opened an issue about this here: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/904